# CORS issue with React app fetching data from Strapi backend on nginx VPS

Tags: reactjs, nginx, cors, strapi, vps

Need some help with a CORS issue!

I am using Hostinger for my website and also a VPS.

I am trying to host a mock e-commerce site (built with React) that fetches data from the Strapi backend on the VPS (which is running nginx on Ubuntu).

When I attempt to fetch data from the VPS using a build of the website on my local machine, I have no issues at all.

I also set up an nginx server on my local machine and can fetch the data from that as well with no issues.

However, when I open my website hosted on Hostinger, I am unable to fetch data from the VPS.

The error I am receiving in the console is:

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading
> the remote resource at https://***.**.**.**/api/categories?populate=*.
> (Reason: CORS request did not succeed). Status code: (null).

When I look at the GET request, this is what I am shown:

> GET https://1**.**.**.**/api/categories?populate=* Transferred: 0 GB
> (0 GB size) Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin
>
> GET /api/categories?populate=* undefined
>
> Host: 1**.**.**.** User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64;
> rv:108.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/108.0
>
> Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
>
> Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5 Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
>
> Origin: null
>
> Authorization: bearer 3***************************4
>
> Connection: keep-alive
>
> Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty
>
> Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
>
> Sec-Fetch-Site: cross-site

Any ideas on how to tackle this issue?

Or even where the issue is originating? Is it the VPS, the client or something else I'm missing?

Thanks for reading!